# How to pass content child to component in storybook for angular?

Tags: angular, storybook

I was trying to write one storybook using angular, but I was stuck here, I  don't know how to mount a component with a content child.

Here is a simple component that I plan to write storybook for it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: `
         <span>bar</span>
         <ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class FooComponent {
    constructor(){}
}
```

The storybook code:

```
storiesOf('Foo', module).add('Default', () => ({
        component: FooComponent
    })
);
```

And the above story is for the component looks like: `<foo></foo>`

***But how can I write a story that let the component looks like: `<foo><span>content child</span></foo>` ?***

**I want to write a story for the component that with content child `<span>content child</span>`.**

I will be very appreciated if you have any idea about this, thanks ~

Comment: Can u please provide more informations? Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this question make sense to you?  I made some changes to the questions.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I figure out one workaround solution to solve this, by adding another component that will represent the component with the content child, then write a story for this additional component.

```
@Component{
  selector: 'foo-with-child',
  template: `<foo>content child</foo>`
class FooComponentWithChild {}

storiesOf('Foo', module).add('with Content Child', () => ({
        component: FooComponentWithChild
    })
);
```

Answer (score -3):

You should add an `@Input() content` attribute to the component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: '<span>{{content}}</span>'
})
export class FooComponent {
    @Input('content') content
    constructor(){}
}
```

and set the props like this:

```
storiesOf('Foo', module).add('Default', () => ({
    component: FooComponent
    props: {
      content: 'Content child'
    }
    })
);
```

For more information check this [introduction storybook for Angular](https://alligator.io/angular/storybook-angular/)

Comment: Actually, I just want to use the content child to apply some values to the component, not the input property.

I'd like to write the component like: `<foo>content child for foo</foo>`
And in the Foo component's template using `ng-content` to render it, like: `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Comment: Hmm, not really sure what you mean. Do you want to add a component inside the component?

Comment: Yeah, almost here. I write a component that will take an inside component and render it properly. using it like: `<foo><span>child conent</span></foo>`. and I want to write a story for `foo` component in this situation, does this make sense to you? forgive my poor English, thanks anyway :)